# How to setup second ETH adapter for host while using first for Hyper-V VMs only?

Tags: windows, networking, hyper-v, windows-11

Windows 11 x64 Pro. I have Hyper-V which has an external switch which is used by VMs.

I have 2 Ethernet ports on the machine. I want to use 2nd port for everything except Hyper-V VMs.

**How to setup that and how to test that the all relevant traffic goes into 2nd port?**

**TLDR** I did set both adapters to different metrics, tried 1/2 and 2/4 but it didnt work. But if I **set "main" adapter metric to 1 and keep secondary (Hyper-V) as Automatic - it works**

EDIT: Tried to change metrics as suggested but it doesnt work (sse the pics)

```
192.168.0.204 (supposed to be main adapter)
192.168.0.202 (hyper-v external switch)
```

Note the main adapter shows 258 metric in routes despite being set to 2 in the properties (the other one set to 4 atm). Tried metrics 1 and 2 respectively with same result.

[image: main adapter settings]

[image: route table]

**However** there is a warning once I try to save new manual metric value which I dont understand.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may connect the external switch to the first network adapter.

Then set higher the priority of the second network adapter as follows:

- Run *Start > View Network Connections*
- Open the Properties of the network adapter by right-clicking it
- Open the Properties of the "Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)"
  or "Internet Protocol Version 6 (TCP/IPv6)"
- Select the Advanced button
- Uncheck "Automatic metric" and set it to a low value such as `1`
- Click OK
- Reboot.